# Why can't we unmarshal data into beans using univocity parser in apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel, univocity

Univocity parser supports reading data into bean when it is written in plain java - https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial#using-annotations-to-map-your-java-beans

But when univocity is used with camel, it only unmarshals the data into a list or a map -
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/univocity-csv-dataformat.html#_unmarshalling_usages

Why is reading into beans supported in univocity but it is not supported when it is used with camel?

Answer (score 1):

Univocity has a ton of features and support for bean mapping has not been implemented in its Camel component. You are welcome to create a JIRA and contributions is welcome to add such feature.

Comment: Hi Claus, I tried to create an issue in Jira, but I didn't find 'camel-univocity' under components. Can you suggest which component should I choose from the drop-down?

Comment: You do not have to fill in a component, just leave it blank